# Alternating sum involving binomial coefficient

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, binomial-coefficients

How do I find the following sum?
$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{2n\choose2k}$

Tried to simplify it somehow but got nothing less complicated.

Comment: Maybe the binomial theorem, $(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^{n-k}y^k$, could help. Maybe with $2n$ instead of $n$, and $x=1$ and $y=-1$ ? Then see if you can manipulate it into what you actually want.

Comment: Look closely at $(1+i)^{2n}$ and $(1-i)^{2n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} {{2n}\choose{2k}} (-1)^k &= \text{ even terms of } \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n} {{2n}\choose{k}} i^k \\
&= \text{ real part of } \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n} {{2n}\choose{k}} i^k \\
&= \text{ real part of } (1+i)^{2n}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may observe that, by the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement),
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{2n\choose2k}&=\sum_{k=0}^n {2n\choose2k}i^{2k}
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n\choose2k}i^{2k}
\\\\&=\sum_{p=0}^{2n} {2n\choose p}\frac{i^{p}+(-i)^p}2
\\\\&=\dfrac{(1+i)^{2n}+(1-i)^{2n}}{2}
\\\\&=(2i)^{n}\frac{1+(-1)^n}2.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Why is your last line not $\dfrac{(1+i)^{2n}+(1-i)^{2n}}{2}$?

Comment: @Henry Because $(1+i)^{2n}=\big(\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}\big)^{2n}=(2i)^n$.

Comment: OK.  So you are saying the sum is $2^n$ when $n$ is a multiple of $4$, it is $-2^n$ when $n $ is even but not a multiple of $4$, and is $0$ when $n$ is odd.  That works for me.