# How to prove this general form of the BBP formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

### Question

> How to prove the general form of the [BBP(Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) formula?
>
> Prove this formula is always true, or find a counterexample $k$ that makes the formula invalid:

$$
π≟\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{1}{2^{4kn+4k+4 n+3}}\sum_{m=0}^{8k+8}\frac{ (1-i)^{m+1}+(1+i)^{m+1}-2^{m/2}\left((-1)^m+1\right)}{8kn+8k+8n-m+8},∀ k∈\mathbb{N}
$$

### Background

I discovered this formula while solving this problem:

[Find pattern for BBP-type π formulas for order 28?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343941/a-pattern-for-bbp-type-pi-formulas-one-for-order-28/4830200#4830200)

When $k = 0$, the original BBP formula is given, in which the coefficients are not simplified, and the rules are not obvious after simplification.

$$
π=\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}4^{-2 n-1} \left(\frac{16}{8 n+1}-\frac{8}{8 n+4}-\frac{4}{8 n+5}-\frac{4}{8 n+6}\right)
$$

When $k = 1$, the following formula is given:

$$
π=\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}4^{-4 n-3} \left(\frac{256}{16 n+1}-\frac{128}{16 n+4}-\frac{64}{16 n+5}-\frac{64}{16 n+6}+\frac{16}{16 n+9}-\frac{8}{16 n+12}-\frac{4}{16 n+13}-\frac{4}{16 n+14}\right)
$$

When $k = 2$, the following formula is given:

$$
π=\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}4^{-6 n-5} \left(\frac{4096}{24 n+1}-\frac{2048}{24 n+4}-\frac{1024}{24 n+5}-\frac{1024}{24 n+6}+\frac{256}{24 n+9}-\frac{128}{24 n+12}-\frac{64}{24 n+13}-\frac{64}{24 n+14}+\frac{16}{24 n+17}-\frac{8}{24 n+20}-\frac{4}{24 n+21}-\frac{4}{24 n+22}\right)
$$

Numerical verification of higher order can also be passed.

A quick numerical verification can be done with the following `Mathematica` code.

```
ExtendBBP[k_] := Inactive[Sum][2^(-3 - 4k - 4n - 4k * n)*Sum[
    ((1-I)^(m+1)+(1+I)^(m+1)-2^(m/2)(1+(-1)^m))/
    (8 + 8k - m + 8n + 8k * n),
    {m, 0, 8 + 8k}], 
    {n, 0, Infinity}
]; 
N[Activate[ExtendBBP[0] - Pi], 200]
N[Activate[ExtendBBP[1] - Pi], 200]
N[Activate[ExtendBBP[2] - Pi], 200]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proposed formula appears to be correct. The considered series can be written as
\begin{align}
 S&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{4kn+4k+4 n+3}}\sum_{m=0}^{8k+8}\frac{ (1-i)^{m+1}+(1+i)^{m+1}-2^{m/2}\left((-1)^m+1\right)}{8kn+8k+8n-m+8}\\
 &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{2k'}\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)k'}}\,\frac{A_m}{(n+1)k'-m/2}\\
 &=\sum_{m=0}^{2k'}A_m\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{nk'}}\,\frac1{nk'-m/2}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
 k'&=4(k+1)\\
 A_m&=(1-i)^{m+1}+(1+i)^{m+1}-2^{m/2}\left((-1)^m+1\right)
\end{align}
Considering the series
\begin{equation}
 f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{nk'}}{nk'-m/2}
\end{equation}
one has
\begin{align}
 \frac{d}{dx}\left[x^{-m/2}f(x)\right]&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{nk'-m/2-1}\\
 &=\frac{x^{k'-m/2-1}}{1-x^{k'}}
\end{align}
which gives
\begin{equation}
 f(x)=x^{m/2}\int_0^x\frac{t^{k'-m/2-1}}{1-t^{k'}}\,dt
\end{equation}
Thus, with $x=1/2$, we have
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{nk'}}\frac1{nk'-m/2}=2^{-m/2}\int_0^{1/2}\frac{t^{k'-m/2-1}}{1-t^{k'}}\,dt
\end{equation}
After inversion of summation and integral, the series reads
\begin{equation}
 S=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{t^{k'-1}}{1-t^{k'}}\,dt\sum_{m=0}^{2k'}A_m \left(2t\right)^{-m/2}
\end{equation}

To evaluate the $m-$summation, $A_m$ is expressed as
\begin{align}
 A_m&=(1-i)^{m+1}+(1+i)^{m+1}-2^{m/2}\left((-1)^m+1\right)\\
 &=\sum_{p=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}p i^p\left( (-1)^p+1 \right)-2^{m/2}\left((-1)^m+1\right)
\end{align}
which gives
\begin{align}
 A_{2r}&=\sum_{p=0}^{2r+1}\binom{2r+1}p i^p\left( (-1)^p+1 \right)-2^{r+1}\\
 &=2\sum_{s=0}^{r}\binom{2r+1}{2s} (-1)^s-2^{r+1}\\
 &=-2^{r+1}\left( 1+\sin\left( \frac{r\pi}{2} \right)-\cos\left( \frac{r\pi}{2} \right)\right)\\
 A_{2r-1}&=\sum_{p=0}^{2r}\binom{2r}p i^p\left( (-1)^p+1 \right)\\
 &=2\sum_{s=0}^{r}\binom{2r}{2s} (-1)^s\\
 &=2^{r+1}\cos\left( \frac{r\pi}{2} \right)
\end{align}
The evaluation of the alternating binomial sums was made using [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1987685/348034). These expressions are discussed for different values of $r\mod4$:
\begin{align}
 A_{8q}=A_{8r+6}&=0\\
 A_{8q+2}&=-2^{4q+3}\\
 A_{8q+4}&=-2^{4q+4}\\
  A_{8q+1}=A_{8q+5}&=0\\
 A_{8q+3}&=-2^{4q+3}\\
 A_{8q+7}&=2^{4q+5}
\end{align}

Accordingly, the $m-$summation is decomposed :
\begin{align}
 \sum_{m=0}^{2k'}A_m \left(2t\right)^{-m/2}&=\sum_{m=0}^{8(k+1)}A_m \left(2t\right)^{-m/2}\\
 &=A_{8(k+1)}t^{-4(k+1)}+\sum_{j=0}^7\sum_{q=0}^{k}A_{8q+j}\left(2t\right)^{-4q-j/2}\\
 &= \sum_{q=0}^{k}\left[A_{8q+2} \left(2t\right)^{-4q-1}
 +A_{8q+3} \left(2t\right)^{-4q-3/2}
 +A_{8q+4} \left(2t\right)^{-4q-2}
 +A_{8q+7} \left(2t\right)^{-4q-7/2}
 \right]\\
 &=\sum_{q=0}^{k}\left[-2^{2} t^{-4q-1}
 -2^{3/2} t^{-4q-3/2}
 -2^{2} t^{-4q-2}
 +2^{3/2}t^{-4q-7/2}
 \right]\\
 &=\frac{-2 t^{11/2} \sqrt{2}+2 \sqrt{2}\, t^{9/2}-4 t^{6}+2 \sqrt{2}\, t^{-4 k +3/2}-2 \sqrt{2}\, t^{-4 k +1/2}+4 t^{2-4 k}}{t^{4} \left(t -1\right) \left(t^{2}+1\right)}\\
 &=\frac{2 \left(t^{4}-t^{-4 k}\right) \left(2 t^{2}-\sqrt{2}\, \sqrt{t}\, \left(1-t \right)\right)}{t^{4} \left(1-t \right) \left(t^{2}+1\right)}
\end{align}
(helped by a CAS!). One obtains thus
\begin{align}
 S&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{t^{4k+3}}{1-t^{4k+4}}\frac{2 \left(t^{4}-t^{-4 k}\right) \left(2 t^{2}-\sqrt{2}\, \sqrt{t}\, \left(1-t \right)\right)}{t^{4} \left(1-t \right) \left(t^{2}+1\right)}\,dt\\
 &=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{2\sqrt2 \left(1-t\right) -4 t^{3/2}}{\sqrt{t}\, \left(t^{2}+1\right) \left(1-t\right)}\,dt
\end{align}
Interestingly, this integral does not depend on $k$. To evaluate this integral, we change first $t=(1-v^2)/2$
\begin{align}
 S&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{2\sqrt2 \left(1-t\right) -4 t^{3/2}}{\sqrt{t}\, \left(t^{2}+1\right) \left(1-t\right)}\,dt\\
 &=-16\int_0^1\frac{v\,dv}{(1+v^2)(v^2-2v-1)}\\
 &=4\int_0^1\frac{dv}{1+v^2}+4\int_0^1\frac{v\,dv}{1+v^2}-4\int_0^1\frac{v-1}{v^2-2v-1}\,dv
\end{align}
The second integral of the latter expression is equal to the third one, as changing $v=\sqrt z$ in the second gives and $v=1-\sqrt{1-w^2}$
\begin{align}
 \int_0^1\frac{v\,dv}{1+v^2}&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{dz}{1+z}\\
 \int_0^1\frac{v-1}{v^2-2v-1}\,dv&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{dw}{1+w}
\end{align}
Finally,
\begin{align}
 S&=4\int_0^1\frac{dv}{1+v^2}\\
 &=\pi
\end{align}
as expected.